# What has happened to the KEVM?

Tags: ethereum, contracts

One of the big selling points of Cardano was EVM compatibility out of the box through the KEVM project.

It now has disappeared as a talking point: Has its development stopped?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Development is alive and kicking.

Alongside our native smart contract language Plutus, we are still on track with the KEVM and its support for languages like Solidity and Glow.

Comment: The question was about the development of the EVM compatibility with Cardano out of box - can you please reference some development on this side? Looking at the code https://github.com/input-output-hk/mantis-cardano it looks pretty dead.

Answer (score 7):

The [KEVM testnet](https://developers.cardano.org/en/virtual-machines/kevm/getting-started/using-the-kevm-devnet/) has been down for more than a month, but it is back up.

I never heard about it being compatible out of the box, there are plans to have it as a side-chain in the future, but there is still a lot of work before that can happen and is probably not in the short-term future.